# SQL max date related issue

Tags: mysql, sql, date, max, intervals

I'm having a bit of an issue with max(date) in SQL.
Basically the problem being that I have to check if latest date entered by id is more than 1 days old and then return that date.

```
   id|  user_id|           send_date
   8 |      90 | 2016-10-21 14:31:14
| 10 |      90 | 2016-10-25 09:56:28
| 11 |      18 | 2016-10-22 09:56:28
| 12 |      19 | 2016-10-21 09:56:28
| 13 |      19 | 2016-10-23 09:56:28
| 13 |      20 | 2016-10-25 09:56:28
```

This is part of a much longer SQL (just the part that I have a problem with):

```
SELECT max(h.send_date) as lastSent 
FROM history h 
WHERE (h.send_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Now what happens is that instead of selecting rows where latest entered date is older than 1 day, I get the latest one that is older than 1 day even if there's a newer entry in the table.

Does anyone have an idea how to change it so that SQL would only return the latest date when it's older that 24h **and** the newest (by user) in the table (in the example, it would have to return nothing because there's an entry less than 24h old)?

Edited the table example a bit. This is what I need to get as a result (user_ids 90 and 20 get's ignored because of 2016-10-25 09:56:28):

```
  18 |  2016-10-22 09:56:28
  19 |  2016-10-23 09:56:28
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (now() is a product specific function.)

Comment: I'm using MySQL

Comment: Not clear enough to me what you are looking for. Can you provide a more detailed example of data and result expected ?

Comment: I don't get what you want, maybe `SELECT user_id, max(h.send_date) as lastSent 
FROM history h GROUP BY user_id HAVING max(h.send_date) < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY`? This returns only users who didn't send within he last 24 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for aggregation function you should  use having and not where

```
SELECT max(h.send_date) as lastSent 
FROM history h 
having  max(h.send_date ) < DATE_SUB(NOW() ,INTERVAL 1 DAY) ;
```

Comment: there is no need to have having clause here, where clause will work if you want to select max(h.send_date)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @RanjitSingh   if the OP need the value of max(max(h.send_date ) for check he must use having clause .. and in mysql he can't use alias in having ..